# Подключение к базе mysql

Tags: php

Добрый день!

```
php -v
```

> PHP 7.0.24 (cli) (built: Sep 30 2017 10:10:28) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

При попытке выполнения скрипта

```
$user='test';
$password='test';
$database='test';
$host='localhost';
$link = mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database) or die (mysqli_error($link));
$q="select * from workers limit 1";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$q);
echo $result;
?>
```

выдается ошибка

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli() in /usr/share/nginx/html/test/index.php:6
>   Stack trace:
>   `#0 {main}`
>     thrown in /usr/share/nginx/html/test/index.php on line 6

В гугле один ответ подключите библиотеку php_mysqli.dll

Но у меня рядом крутится облако на owncloud и нормально работает с базой.
В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Нужно добавить `new mysqli(...)`. оператор `new`.

Comment: я что то сделал не так? 
$link =new mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die (mysqli_error($link));
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli_connect' not found in /usr/share/nginx/html/test/index.php:6

Comment: или так PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /usr/share/nginx/html/test/index.php:6

Comment: Вы вызываете функцию `mysqli` - которой не существует, так как вы используете объект, то и работать нужно  с `$link` объектом и его методами и свойствами, а для этого нужно использовать оператор `new` перед названием класса `mysqli`.

Comment: можно пожалуйста для тупеньких? пытался сделать по аналогии с http://theory.phphtml.net/books/php/sql/ пункт Устанавливаем соединение с БД

Answer (score 0):

В место mysqli будет mysqli_connect

Comment: то же самое PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /usr/share/nginx/html/test/index.php:6

Comment: У тебя не установлено расширение mysqli.
В конфиге PHP добавь extension=mysqli.so

Comment: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это:
ООП вариант: `$link = new mysqli(params);`
Процедурный вариант: `$link = mysqli_connect(params);`
Если появляется та же ошибка, проверьте установлено (включено) ли расширение MySQLi (MySQL Improved), вызвав функцию php_info().

Comment: В выводе команды php_info() действительно не нашел ничего про mysql. Как его теперь установить?

Comment: Не морочьте себе голову, если новичок. Лучше скачайте и установите OSPanel . Она включает в себя всё, что только можно и хорошо настроено, а если нужна доп. настройка - то есть обширная документация. Для новичка (да и не только) лучше не придумаешь

Comment: Спасибо за совет уже есть денвер и php storm. Да просто решил сделать тестовую страничку на своем VPS. Практического толку никакого но привычка добивать до конца не дает покоя :)

Answer (score 0):

При попытке установить 
yum install php-mysqli
получаем ошибку 
Error: php71w-common conflicts with php70w-common-7.0.24-1.w7.x86_64
Решил немного другим способом
нашел что провайдит php-mysqli в php70w вот ссылка
https://webtatic.com/packages/php70/
php70w-mysql    php-mysqli, php_database
php70w-mysqlnd  php-mysqli, php_database

поставил php70w-mysql, ошибка ушла
теперь " Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string"
Но это уже скорее моя логическая или синтаксическая ошибка в коде.
Всем спасибо за ответы!